# Cannot pull origin dev due to unrelated conflict in Git

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea, gitlab

I pull a branch (let's say issue-100) from origin for review and after review I switched to local dev branch without modifying this issue-100 branch. There are some conflicts with this branch, but I did not touch it and just create a new branch after pulling dev branch from origin. But, interestingly, Git gives "Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result." messages. I just followed these steps:

```
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev
--> gives error, then I abort merging in IntelliJ

git branch 
git branch -D issue-100
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev
--> gives error, then I abort merging in IntelliJ
```

So, I did not push issue-100 to origin, but it gives error. How should I fix this problem?

Comment: What is the output of `git status`? Add it to the question, please.

Comment: Ok... besides needing git status, just a question: did your local and the remove `dev` branches diverge? Specifically, are there revisions in your local `dev` that are not in the remote `dev`?

Comment: Yes, there are some messages indicating diverge. Then, should I delete local dev and pull from origin?

Comment: @Jasmine may I ask you why do you abort merge? It looks like you have some commits in `dev` branch that do not exist in origin/dev and when you do pull, incoming commits conflict with the existing (local) commits

Comment: You right, but I did not any changes actually and the cause is review a branch by pulling to my local. So, there will be any problem to delete and pull dev branch I think as I have no update for push. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conflicts are showing up because of this discrepancy between your local dev and remote dev. If local dev is supposed to be just like remote dev, you should put the branch right there:

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard origin/dev # before running this, make sure there are no pending changes laying aroind your working tree as they would be lost
```

Now local dev and remote dev are exactly the same (content and history). Everything should be back to normal.

There's this question in my head about why people should *not* use a local copy of a shared remote branch, but it is waaaaay broader than your question in point and I happen to hold an opinion that is against common wisdom (I think people should not keep a local copy of a remote shared branch but..... that's just my opinion).

Comment: What about deleting `dev` branch and pulling from origin? As a result it seems to give the same result with a dev branch that is exactly the same with the dev in origin.

Comment: That could also work. like `git branch -D dev; git checkout -b dev origin/dev`

Comment: or also: `git branch -f dev origin/dev` (works as long as you are not on dev).

Comment: I follow this way, but not sure it is also a proper way? `git checkout -b new_branch` and `git branch -D dev ` then `git checkout dev`  and finally  `git pull origin dev`  :) seems to be longer but maybe also a proper way to remember easily using the commonly used commands. Any idea?

Comment: That sounds about right..... only thing is that there is no need to do the first checkout creating a new branch. You can _disconnect_ from dev by doing `git checkout --detach`.

Comment: What does this `git branch -f dev origin/dev` do? Does it delete and recreate `dev` or fetch from `origin/dev` ?

Comment: it forces git to move the branch pointer `dev` (in other words, **the branch**) to the revision that `origin/dev` is pointing to.

Comment: So, what is the  proper and shortest way? Maybe with permistting on the dev branch?

Comment: They are all fine. As long as you understand each one of the commands that you are running (my way, your way), it will be fine. potato, potato. It's one of the wonders of git... it's super-flexible in terms of ways to achieve the same thing.

Comment: The simplest, for sure is `git branch -f dev origin/dev`. If you were working on dev, then just run `git checkout --detach` to disconnect so that it allows you to move the branch. Then you can checkout dev again.

Comment: **"potato, potato..."** :))) Wonderful explanations. I just wanted to be sure that, if the following statements true or not: >>

Comment: `git checkout -b dev origin/dev` --> create a new branch called `dev` by copying the `origin/dev` (meaning that copy `origin/dev` to `local/dev`.

Comment: that one? So so. Almost there. What it does is create a _local_ branch called `dev` that will be at exactly the same revision that `origin/dev` is pointing at (to your current knowledge... it might have moved on the remote repo and so on, you know how it works with distributed VCSs) _and_ will check it out.

Comment: I wanted to explain because I don't know _exactly_ what you mean with _copying_. There is no real _copying_ involved there. A new branch is created (which is just a pointer to a revision) and then HEAD (which is **always** where you are standing in git) is placed there and the working tree is made to have the same content of that revision.

Comment: Hmm, very useful explanation. Then when pull or fetching, I get the version that the pointers refers?

Comment: Let's first tackle `fetching`: refresh the information that I have about the references on a given remote repo. In other words, get where the branches and tags on that remote repo are. It doesn't move any local references, no _local_ branches are messed with.

Comment: Many thanks again. Voted up and marked as answer

Comment: `pulling` is a two step process. First: `run fetch`. Then, merge (or rebase) my current branch with the remote branch that my current local branch is `tracking` (which normally means _the branch that was used as the base to create it_, but it can be changed at any time after a branch is created).

Comment: There are exceptions.... for example, if you use a local branch to create another local branch. If you are on the child local branch and you ask to pull, I don't think there will be a fetch because the `parent` branch is also local. That's why in workflows that use a local `dev` branch (like yours) you first checkout `dev`, pull from it{s remote parent, then switch to a given feature branch and then pull again (which then does no fetching, just merge or rebase from the local `dev`).

Comment: And sure, no problem. As long as you get the basics right (like `branches are just pointers to revisions`), git starts to feel like home.

Comment: Do you mean that the scenario that I gave above ("I follow this way..." message) will not work? Of course I create new_branch from dev ad then delete dev. Will it work?

Comment: Ok... that's an interesting point. You delete local `dev` branch after you create the feature branch? That's not required. You can keep the local branch live and just run `git pull` from it when you want to get it `in sync` with the remote branch. Deleting it and recreating it _also_ works, it's just not necessary. Did i get it right?

Comment: Nope, you do **not** delete local dev branch because then the whole problem that you posted would not show up ever. So you are talking about something else that I didn't get.